# ListView/DataGridView grouping's expand when item selected

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I finish a ListView grouping and add a expander control.

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

The `IsExpanded` like

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
```

and I set `lv.SelectedIndex` to change selection, but it don't work!

I have no idea.

Comment: A ListViewItem is not a visual ancestor of a GroupItem. It is a child of a GroupItem. Are you trying to selecting/expanding a particular group or what are you trying to do?

Comment: I change ListViewItem to GroupItem, but don't work.
I want to implement a search function to find a keyword from list, then auto selected. So the group need to expanding when list find result.

Answer (score 0):

**Xaml Design:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="groupheaderstyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True" Background="White" Foreground="Black">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gropname}" />
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="dgdata" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="269" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource groupheaderstyle}">
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DataGridRowsPresenter />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

**Xaml Design.cs**

```
 public class group
    {
        public string groupname { get; set; }
        public string CLgroup { get; set; }
        public string displayname { get; set; }
    }
    public Window4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<group> samdata = new ObservableCollection<group>
        {
            new group{groupname="Group1",CLgroup="xxx",displayname="demo1"},
            new group{groupname="Group1",CLgroup="yyy",displayname="demo2"},
            new group{groupname="Group1",CLgroup="yyy",displayname="demo2"},
        };          
        ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(samdata);
        collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("groupname"));
        dgdata.ItemsSource = collection;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, but no help for me.